# Three.js Rotate sphere to arbitrary position

Tags: javascript, web, 3d, three.js

Using Three.js I have a sphere (globe) and several sprites attached to volcano points. I can rotate (spin) the globe and the sprites stay in their positions because they're added as a group to the sphere.

Now I want to be able to spin the globe to an arbitrary position using a button. How can I do this? For example if the point I want to spin to is at the back of the globe, how can I rotate the globe so it's in the front?

This code is essentially what I have right now. A main mesh which I add sprite to.

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>


<script src="three.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var scene, camera, renderer;
  var geometry, material, mesh;

  init();
  animate();

  function init() {

      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
      camera.position.z = 1000;

      material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: false } );

      geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 159, 32, 32 );
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add( mesh );

      var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "sprite1.png" );
      var material2 = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map:map, color:0x00ff00 } );
      var sprite1 = new THREE.Sprite( material2 );
      sprite1.position.set(100,100,100);
      sprite1.scale.set(40,40,40);
      mesh.add(sprite1);

      var sprite2 = new THREE.Sprite( material2);
      sprite2.position.set(-100,-100,-100);
      sprite2.scale.set(30,30,30);
      mesh.add(sprite2);

      var sprite3 = new THREE.Sprite(material2);
      sprite3.position.set(100,-100,100);
      sprite3.scale.set(20,20,20);
      mesh.add(sprite3);

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha:true});
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  }

  function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Diagram example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ3Zd.png)

Comment: can you show what code you have already? it would help

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach:

```js
// as sprite is a child of mesh get world position
var spritePos = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(sprite.matrixWorld);

// get the vectors for calculating angle
var cv3 = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(camera.position, mesh.position);
var sv3 = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(spritePos, mesh.position);

// we only want to rotate around y-axis, so only the angle in x-z-plane is relevant
var cv2 = new THREE.Vector2(cv3.x, cv3.z);
var sv2 = new THREE.Vector2(sv3.x, sv3.z);

// normalize Vectors
cv2.normalize();
sv2.normalize();

// dot product
var dot = cv2.dot(sv2);

// angle to between sprite and camera in radians
// cosinus is from 1 to -1, so we need to normalize and invert it and multiply it with PI to get proper angle
var angle = (1 - (dot + 1) / 2) * Math.PI;

// is sprite left or right from camera?
if(spritePos.x < 0)
  mesh.rotation += angle;
else
  mesh.rotation -= angle;
```

Now, I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jljgO19F4KISNvRphFpy?p=preview).

It seems a bit inaccurate as it always rotates a bit left or right to the very front position. Maybe it's due to the cosinus near to some specific angles.

Also keep in mind that the determination whether the sprite is left or right from the camera is a bit more difficult if camera or mesh is somewhere else in the scene.

*Explanation after dot product:*

The dot product gives the angle of two vectors as cosinus. So we get a value between -1 and 1. e.g. `cos(0) = 1` `cos(PI/2) = 0` `cos(PI) = -1` So at the moment is 0° = 1 and 180° = -1.

We want to get the angle in radians to rotate the mesh in position. So first we normalize it `(dot + 1) / 2`, so 0° = 1 and 180° = 0.

Then invert it (0° = 0, 180° = 1) and multiply with PI (0° = 0, 180° = PI).

Now, we have the angle to rotate, but we don't know if need to rotate to the left or to the right, that's why I check if the sprite is left or right from camera.

I don't know if it's explanation enough or if it's comprehensable at all?

Comment: I understand down to "dot product" section.  I've added a diagram to the original post, hoping I've understood it correctly.  Your code seems to be giving me a fixed rotation each time, not around to the correct point each time. Could you clarify what's happening from "dot product"? I'm guessing it's the angle between the two vectors, then rotate by this amount?

Comment: Yes your diagram is right. I updated my answer. I had to correct some things like `setPositionFromMatrix` to `setFromMatrixPosition` and `>` to `<`. I also made a Plunker as live demo and a explanation.